# How to implement an authentication method using Spring Boot and JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

Using Spring Boot and JPA in Java, I am creating a vending machine simulator whereby there are 2 roles: "BUYER" and "SELLER". I have a table called `users` in a MySQL database that stores users along with their usernames, passwords and their roles. I would like to implement an authentication method that allows me to specify which endpoints can be called based on the role of the user (e.g. anyone can create a new user, buyers can purchase products from the vending machine and sellers can add new products). Most of the tutorials I have seen have been using an old version of Spring Boot Security and using things like the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` which have since been deprecated and therefore I cannot follow the tutorials and other ones are using h2 or other in memory databases. How can I implement this authentication using MySQL.

Worth noting I am using Postman to test my requests.

`users` table:

```
+----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int           | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| deposit  | decimal(38,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| role     | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| username | varchar(255)  | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Additional bonus, how can I encrypt the user's password when saving to the database?

---

UPDATE

As per some of the suggested solutions, I have implemented the following:

`SecurityConfiguration` class:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration
{
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("users").hasAnyAuthority("BUYER", "SELLER")// Allow all create requests without authentication
                        .requestMatchers("create-user").hasRole("SELLER")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                        )
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

`SecurityUserLoader` class:

```java
@Component
public class SecurityUserLoader implements UserDetailsService
{
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public SecurityUserLoader(UserRepository userRepository)
    {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException
    {
        User loadedUser = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (loadedUser == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid username or password.");
        }
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                loadedUser.getUsername(),
                loadedUser.getPassword(),
                true,
                true,
                true,
                true,
                Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + loadedUser.getRole().toString()))
        );
    }
}
```

Thought it'd also be useful to add the `User` object, `Role` enum and my `UserController` class:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int userId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "username", unique = true)
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "role")
    private Role role;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "deposit")
    private BigDecimal deposit;

    public User() {}

    public User(String username, String password, Role role, BigDecimal deposit)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
        this.deposit = deposit;
    }

    public int getId()
    {
        return userId;
    }

    public String getUsername()
    {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username)
    {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password)
    {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Role getRole()
    {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role)
    {
        this.role = Role.valueOf(role);
    }

    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public BigDecimal getDeposit()
    {
        return deposit;
    }

    public void setDeposit(BigDecimal deposit)
    {
        this.deposit = deposit;
    }

}
```

```java
public enum Role
{
    BUYER("buyer"),
    SELLER("seller");

    private final String role;

    Role(String role)
    {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public String getRole()
    {
        return role;
    }

    public static Role getRoleEnum(String roleString)
    {
        return switch (roleString.toLowerCase()) {
            case "buyer" -> Role.BUYER;
            case "seller" -> Role.SELLER;
            default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException("Role [" + roleString
                    + "] not supported.");
        };
    }
}
```

```java
@RestController
public class UserController
{
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public List<User> getUsers(@RequestParam("username") Optional<String> usernameSubstring)
    {
        return usernameSubstring
                .map(userRepository::getUsers)
                .orElse(userRepository.findAll());
    }

    @PostMapping("/create-user")
    public UserOrError createUser(@RequestBody User user)
    {
        return userService.createUser(user);
    }

    @PostMapping("/user-exists")
    public boolean userExists(@RequestBody User user)
    {
        return userService.userExists(user);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I make a request to any of these 3 endpoints in Postman, I get status `401 Unauthorized` and get the follow exception in console:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"
    at org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder$UnmappedIdPasswordEncoder.matches(DelegatingPasswordEncoder.java:289) ~[spring-security-crypto-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder.matches(DelegatingPasswordEncoder.java:237) ~[spring-security-crypto-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.additionalAuthenticationChecks(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:77) ~[spring-security-core-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:147) ~[spring-security-core-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201) ~[spring-security-core-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:176) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:351) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To configure the authorization in new manner implement a configuration class like this:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/", "/signup", "register").permitAll() // Permit all users create users
                        .requestMatchers("/buyers/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_BUYER") // Restrict buyers endpoints to only the buyer role
                        .requestMatchers("/sellers/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_SELLER") // Restrict sellers endpoints to only the seller role
                );
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

In the snippet above password manager is configured as a bean. In your save method, You can inject and use it to hash the password. Also for authentication and loading your database users, Implement a class like the following code:

```
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SecurityUserLoader implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public SecurityUserLoader(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User loadedUser = userRepository.findByEmail(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Could not found a user with given name"));
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                loadedUser.email,
                loadedUser.password,
                true,
                true,
                true,
                true,
                Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(loadedUser.getRole()))
        );
    }
}
```

To explain these codes briefly, The first snippet codes and configs tell Spring what roles can access what endpoints. The second snippet is used in authentication when a user password is retrieved from the database to match it with credentials. Then finally if everything was fine it's role will be determined.

Comment: I have attempted this solution but it's still not working as expected. I have updated the post to show the issues I'm now facing.

Comment: @mdaabis i saw your code. The problem is you restrcited create-user endpoint in your security config. Just remove the requestMatchers(create-user).rolle(seller) to fix it. After the fix steal you will get an forbidden error. To fix this, In the config Just disable CSRF.

Comment: Also the mapping of your roles to your endpoints is wrong because in the hasAnyAuthority method you should pass authorities rather than roles. The authority is like this  ROLE_{YOUR_ROLE}

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's working a little better now, thank you very much. Now I need to have it use the login credentials in my `users` table in MySQL

Answer (score 2):

instead of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter I am using the following configuration to add BASIC authentication and require Authority ADMIN for /api/admin* endpoint, than permit some html, css, js files. Could be a start...

```
@Configuration
    protected static class SecurityConfiguration
    {
        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
        {   
            http.httpBasic()
                .and().authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/admin/*")
                .hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .requestMatchers("/createuser","/index.html", "/", "/home", "/login", "/*.css", "/*.js", "/favicon.ico")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
            return http.build();
        }

    }
```

Comment: I attempted this but I am getting the same exceptions I put in my post update